# $.ajax within jquery plugin not updating variable

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpTpK/

The issue I am having is that the title variable is not updated/changed when the $.ajax is executed, I know that the ajax call is working as I have tried replacing the line

`title = $(xml).find("title").text();`

with

`console.log($(xml).find("title").text());`

and sure enough it does return the title however when using the orginal line the variable title doesn't change

I have tried and it does work putting the ajax call outside (function($){})(jQuery);

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getPost = function(options) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var defaults = {
            method: "html",
            blogID: "",
            postID: "",
            done: null
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var title;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/724793682641096478/posts/default/3551136550258768001",
            dataType: "xml",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(xml) {
                title = $(xml).find("title").text();
            }
        });
        return $this.each(function() {
            if (options.done) {
                options.done.call(undefined, title);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I have tried the below and i have also tried wrapping the ajax in a function such as getTitle(){ajax code here with return title;}

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getPost = function(options) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var defaults = {
            method: "html",
            blogID: "",
            postID: "",
            done: null
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var title;
        getAjax();
        return $this.each(function() {
            if (options.done) {
                options.done.call(undefined, title);
            }
        });

        function getAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/724793682641096478/posts/default/3551136550258768001",
                dataType: "xml",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                async: false,
                success: function(xml) {
                    title = $(xml).find("title").text();
                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The return will almost always happen before the AJAX request call the function supplied to success.

Comment: @nhahtdh   not **almost**  ... **always**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I have spent ages trying to figure it (I didn't ask out of laziness :P), regardless here's the solution for those interested :)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getPost = function(options) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var defaults = {
            method: "html",
            done: null
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var title;
        var sorf;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/724793682641096478/posts/default/3551136550258768001",
            dataType: "xml",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(xml) {
                title = $(xml).find("title").text();
                sorf = 1;
            },
            error: function(){
                sorf = 0;
            },
            complete: function() {
                returnvals(sorf);
            }
        });

        function returnvals(sorf) {
         if(sorf){
         //success
            return $this.each(function() {
                if (options.done) {
                    options.done.call(undefined, title);
                }
            });
         }else{// failure}
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why `complete`? Shouldn't the call be in `success`? When the request fails, `complete` will also be called.

Comment: oh sorry :/ that's not the whole portion of my plugin, it will pass a parameter when there is an error, my bad should have mentioned that

Comment: I don't know, it's your own solution to your problem, so you know it best. I just find it weird, but if it is your requirement then it should be OK.